# Checking whether an analytic function is a zero function or not

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

True or False:
Let $\gamma: [0, 1] \rightarrow \{z ∈ C | |z| ≤ 1\}$ be a non-constant continuous mapping such that $\gamma(0) = 0$. Let $f$ be an analytic function in the disc $\{z ∈ C | |z| < 2\}$, such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Then, there exists $\tau$ such that $0 <  \tau< 1$ and such that for all $0 < t < \tau$, we have that $f(\gamma(t))\neq 0$.

I think the statement is true. We try to prove it using contradiction method.

If possible assume that for each $0<\tau<1$ we get at least one$0<t<\tau$ such that $f(\gamma(t))=0$.
In particular for each $n\in \mathbb N$ we get $0<t_n<\frac{1}{n}$ such that $f(\gamma(t_n))=0$. Now $t_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $.  Since $\gamma$ is a continuous function we get $\gamma(t_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. So we get a sequence $\{ \gamma(t_n) \}$ in $\{z:|z|<2 \}$ which converges in $\{z:|z|<2 \}$ . So by identity theorem $f$ must be a zero function which is not possible as $f(1)=1$. Hence our supposition is wrong.

Am I correct?

Comment: You need conditions on $\gamma$ to exclude all those points being zero for example; take $t\sin 1/t$ to see how things can go wrong

Comment: You mean $\gamma (t_n)$ must all be different

Comment: not necessary all, but infinitely many and that as noted may not happen for $\gamma$ as described (and note that by taking $\gamma(t)=t^{10000} \sin {1/t}$ say, one can make $\gamma$ differentiable a bunch of times so rectifiable say is not enough)

Comment: Taking $\gamma(t)=\exp\left(-\frac1{t^2}\right)\sin \left(\frac1t\right)$ one can also obtain a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function

Comment: @Conrad Then is the statement true or false? Some hint may be helpful

Comment: the statement is false as stated - it would be true if $\gamma$ is say a Jordan arc